# Search functionality in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

I am following this tutorial. I get a lot of red errors due using Named Tuple, not a simple Array as it is in a tutorial. I need a tuple, so can somebody provide right code for my problem?

I have this code:

```
var myData = [Data]()

// Adding data to the array
var newData = Data(category: "Lorem", name: "Ipsum")
myData.append(newData)
```

I get first error here:

```
controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

any help?

Comment: What is the error message...and what does it have to do with the Data-related code?

Comment: Just says expected declaration.

Answer (score 1):

My solution. And you should add `UISearchResultsUpdating`, `UISearchControllerDelegate`, `UISearchBarDelegate`

```
var dataForSearch: [Music]? = nil
var searchController: UISearchController!
var searchPredicate: NSPredicate!

 func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.dataForSearch?.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    var searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
    if searchController.active == true {
        searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nameSong contains[c] %@", searchText)
        dataForSearch = self.fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects?.filter() {
           return self.searchPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0)
        } as! [Music]?
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    searchController = ({
        var controllerSearch = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controllerSearch.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.searchBar.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.definesPresentationContext = false // default false
        controllerSearch.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        controllerSearch.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controllerSearch.searchResultsUpdater = self 
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controllerSearch.searchBar
        return controllerSearch
    })()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: you should add    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Comment: If I put NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate with other delegates I get an error http://d.pr/i/27YN

Comment: `class SongsTVC: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating`

Comment: Page Not Found @Antonija

Comment: you should add import CoreData and Foundation in your class

Comment: But I am not using Core Data, all my data is in a Named Tuple because I am a newbie and Core Data is too scary for me now.

Comment: @Antonija http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244530/how-to-filter-object-array-in-updatesearchresultsforsearchcontroller-when-using

Comment: This must help! Thanks!